# Issue in saving project to default in pepper robot

Tags: pepper

I am facing trouble in saving project to pepper from choregraphe. The project I updated is not getting saved once I restart the pepper. The changes I made are not reflected.  I don't have any errors in the code or blocks

I followed the below steps

1. Connected to pepper
2. Set the behavior to default
3. Package and install current project to robot

and also tried to delete the already existing behavior from behavior list but it is not happening.
I am seeing two behaviors in the list once I connect to pepper.
One is my own behavior and the other is .lastuploadedchroegraphebehavior.

Comment: Do you want pepper to run your app every time you turn the robot on?
Pepper is designed around the dialog, so you will make your own life much easier if you can accept to use a voice command to run it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Set the behavior to default" - if you mean the little flag in the Robot Applications list, that's something you do *after* installing the app on Pepper, so it's strange that you say you do that before installing it to the robot.

You might want to try using [launch trigger conditions](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/triggerconditions.html), which usually play better with Autonomous Life.